# Bug in recursive binary search method?

Tags: recursion, search, binary-search

I am trying to write a method to perform binary search on an array of persons. The method should return the index that the person is found at, or -1 if it doesn't exist. For some reason, the method seems to return -1 even when the person is in the array. Please help I am a beginner.

```
public static int binarySearchRecursive(Person[] a, Person p) {
    int right = a.length -1;
    int left = 0;
    return binarySearchRecursive(a, p, left, right);
}
private static int binarySearchRecursive(Person[] a, Person p, int left, int right) {
    int mid = (left + right) / 2; 

    if (a[mid].compareTo(p) == 0) 
        return mid;

    if (left == right) 
        return -1;

    else {
        if (a[mid].compareTo(p) > 0) {
            return binarySearchRecursive(a, p, left, mid);
        }
        else {
            return binarySearchRecursive(a, p, mid, left);
        }
    }
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person s = new Person("shlomo",13);
    Person m = new Person("menachem",15);
    Person y = new Person("yehuda",18);
    Person a = new Person("atara",20);



    Person [] array = {s, m, y, a};
```

Comment: Can  you post  an  example of an array of `People` that fails for you. I did a quick test and it works properly in my test. I suspect it may work sometimes but only fail for some inputs.

Comment: @user1118321 I posted the array that I used. It does not work when I search for y in the array.

Comment: Could you provide class Person code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems I can see:

1. In the second recursive call, you're passing `mid` for the left bound and `left` for the right bound. That doesn't seem right.
2. If you search for the last `Person`, the calculation of `mid` never advances, and `left`  never equals `right`, so it recurses infinitely.